# SQL Server pivot using case statement

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to pivot out some data and I think I need to incorporate a case statement in my pivot code but I'm not sure how. I have the table below:

```
ID      AreaCode
1001    1501
1001    1502
1001    2301
1031    1010
1031    3012
1048    2304
1048    3012
1048    4022
```

The first digit of each AreaCode refers to a body area, I'm using the code below to indicate which body area is affected:

```
select id,
case when left(areaID,1)=1 then 'Yes' end Head,
case when left(areaID,1)=2 then 'Yes' end Face,
case when left(areaID,1)=3 then 'Yes' end Neck,
case when left(areaID,1)=4 then 'Yes' end Abdo
from #testcase
```

Which gives me the following:

```
id      Head    Face    Neck    Abdo
1001    Yes     NULL    NULL    NULL
1001    Yes     NULL    NULL    NULL
1001    NULL    Yes     NULL    NULL
1031    Yes     NULL    NULL    NULL
1031    NULL    NULL    Yes     NULL
1048    NULL    Yes     NULL    NULL
1048    NULL    NULL    Yes     NULL
1048    NULL    NULL    NULL    Yes
```

However, I need my output table to contain one row for each id, like so:

```
id      Head    Face    Neck    Abdo
1001    Yes     Yes     Null    Null
1031    Yes     Null    Yes     Null
1048    Null    Yes     Yes     Yes
```

Can incorporate my case statement in a pivot to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `aggregate` on top of `case` statements

```
SELECT id,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN LEFT(areaID, 1) = 1 THEN 'Yes'
           END) Head,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN LEFT(areaID, 1) = 2 THEN 'Yes'
           END) Face,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN LEFT(areaID, 1) = 3 THEN 'Yes'
           END) Neck,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN LEFT(areaID, 1) = 4 THEN 'Yes'
           END) Abdo
FROM   #testcase
GROUP  BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a real [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) solution instead like this:

```
DECLARE @t table(ID int, AreaCode int)
INSERT @t 
VALUES
  (1001,1501),(1001,1502),(1001,2301),(1031,1010),
  (1031,3012),(1048,2304),(1048,3012),(1048,4022)

SELECT id, [1]Head, [2]Face, [3]Neck, [4]Abdo
FROM  
( 
  SELECT id, left(AreaCode, 1) Area, 'Yes' x
  FROM @t
) p 
PIVOT (Max(x) FOR [Area] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS pvt
```

Result:

```
id    Head  Face  Neck  Abdo
1001  Yes   Yes   NULL  NULL
1031  Yes   NULL  Yes   NULL
1048  NULL  Yes   Yes   Yes
```

Comment: Thanks, have saved this for next time I need to Pivot :)