# T-SQL: List multiple rows for a shared value in one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server that looks something like this:

[image]

What I need is this:

[image]

I tried playing around with Pivot a little bit, but of course that won't work because Pivot isn't trying to flip multiple instances of the same field, it's aggregating over multiple instance of the same field.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can do this in T-SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server pivot using case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671886/sql-server-pivot-using-case-statement)

Comment: you might not need pivot here, however your data on ID 3 seems to be inconsistent with ID 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily using dynamic PIVOT. This is full working example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[DataSource]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[DataSource];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSource]
(
    [ID] SMALLINT
   ,[Value] CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataSource] ([ID], [Value])
VALUES (1, 'A')
      ,(1, 'B')
      ,(1, 'C')
      ,(2, 'A')
      ,(2, 'B')
      ,(3, 'C')
      ,(4, 'A')
      ,(4, 'B')
      ,(4, 'C');

DECLARE @MaxValue INT;

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Value]) AS [ValueID]
    FROM [dbo].[DataSource]
)
SELECT @MaxValue = MAX([ValueID])
FROM DataSource;

DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@DynamicSQLPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicSQLPIVOTColumns = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ',[Value' + CAST([number] AS VARCHAR(4)) + ']'
        FROM master..[spt_values] 
        WHERE [number] BETWEEN 1 AND @MaxValue
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
);

SET @DynamicSQLStatement = N'
SELECT [ID], ' + @DynamicSQLPIVOTColumns + '
FROM
(
    SELECT *
          ,''Value'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Value]) AS VARCHAR(12)) AS [ColumnName]
    FROM [dbo].[DataSource]
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [ColumnName] IN (' + @DynamicSQLPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT;';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement;
```

and the result is:

[image]

Something wrong? The value `C` for the `ID = 3` is in the first column, not in the last. That's because I am not aware how you are defining which value is in which column and I am using `ROW_NUMBER` to create such mapping. I guess in your real data you have a way of doing this.

So, let's say you have additional table like this to define this ordering:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[DataSourceOrdering]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[DataSourceOrdering];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSourceOrdering]
(
    [OrderID] SMALLINT
   ,[Value] CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataSourceOrdering] ([OrderID], [Value])
VALUES (1, 'A')
      ,(2, 'B')
      ,(3, 'C');
```

Then instead using `ROW_NUMBER` to defined the ordering we are going to use this table:

```
DECLARE @MaxValue INT;

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT DSO.[OrderID]
    FROM [dbo].[DataSource] DS
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataSourceOrdering] DSO
        ON DS.[Value] = DSO.[Value]
)
SELECT @MaxValue = MAX([OrderID])
FROM DataSource;

DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@DynamicSQLPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicSQLPIVOTColumns = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ',[Value' + CAST([number] AS VARCHAR(4)) + ']'
        FROM master..[spt_values] 
        WHERE [number] BETWEEN 1 AND @MaxValue
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
);

SET @DynamicSQLStatement = N'
SELECT [ID], ' + @DynamicSQLPIVOTColumns + '
FROM
(
    SELECT DS.*
          ,''Value'' + CAST(DSO.[OrderID] AS VARCHAR(12)) AS [ColumnName]
    FROM [dbo].[DataSource] DS
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataSourceOrdering] DSO
        ON DS.[Value] = DSO.[Value]
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [ColumnName] IN (' + @DynamicSQLPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT;';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
WITH 
t AS (
 SELECT 1 AS ID, 'A' AS Value
 UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'B'
 UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'C'
 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'A'
 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'B'
 UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'C'
 UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'A'
 UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'B'
 UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'C'
)
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Value = 'A' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS Value1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Value = 'B' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS Value2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Value = 'C' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS Value3
  FROM t
 GROUP BY ID
```